# need advise of how people make online shopping website grid layout that is same size without images getting strech?

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, image

I am using bootstrap and vb asp.net but just need advise of how people make online shopping website grid layout that is same size without images getting stretch?

here are some examples: 
http://www.hm.com/us/products/men/shoes
http://ibalenciaga.com/

I created grid layout with each boxes size is: 300x450

```
|---------|
| 300x450 |
| grid    |
| box     |
|         |
|         |
|---------|
```

now ofcouse its easy if all images are this size. but as you know pictures can be easily be different size.
so I create the width same of each of my images.

```
Images: 
900x1000
900x1900
900x1500
900x1200
```

my solutions but they all have there issues:

**1st.** I can set images size to grid-box size but than images will be strech. so I can not do that

**2nd.** Since I am using bootstrap, I can use img-response class. with this all images will have same width but issue is that they all will have different height

**3rd:** i guess i have no choice to make sure all my images that I upload are same 300x450 size. I am not sure if this is a good idea or not.

I know I am all over the place with this post but any advise will be helpful

what is a good solution. so people really post images with same size or do they write code to make images responseable?

Comment: Could use `object-fit: cover;` on the image CSS

Comment: doesnt work for me

Comment: ill just go with solution 3... been researching for 4 months now.. did not found any good answer so far

Comment: You said object-fit doesn't work. Do you mean you just don't like the pictures being cropped or is there another issue with it? (You'd also have to set the width and height in the css)